# R error in updating formula when using variable named 'x':

Tags: r, formula

I'm trying to program a model building function which uses the formula expression but I have some problems understanding how the model `update` function works.

Here's a stripped down function which results an error when using `update` function:

```
modelx <- function(formula) {         
  mf <- mc <- match.call()                         
  mf <- mf[c(1L,  match("formula", names(mf), 0L))]      
  mf[[1L]] <- as.name("model.frame")
  mf <- eval(mf, parent.frame())
  y <- model.response(mf, "numeric")
  mt <- attr(mf, "terms")      
  X <- model.matrix(mt, mf)
  out<-list(y=y,X=X)
  out$call<-mc
  out
}
```

The code is pretty much copied from the start of the `lm` function. Some example data and two models:

```
y<-x<-x1<-x2<-1:10
model<-modelx(y ~ x)
model1<-modelx(y ~ x1)
```

Now updating the first model does not work but second does:

```
 model<-update(model, . ~ . + x2)
    Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x + x2) : 
    invalid type (list) for variable 'x'
 model1<-update(model1, . ~ . + x2)
```

If I add a component `out$terms <- mt` into the output of `modelx`, everything works in both cases. Why is this component needed and why does the update function work without it in the second case but not in the first case?

Comment: Just to be painfully cautious: have you verified that `x` , `x1` , `x2` in your current working environment are still what you expect, i.e. numeric vectors?  What happens, e.g. if you swap the `x*` around in the definitions of your `model` and `model1` ?

Comment: Yes I verified this by starting new empty R session, swapped `x`s and error remains (after swapping `model` works and `model1` does not)

Comment: I don't have time to hack through this at the moment, but: `update` and friends are generally much more reliable when you pass the variables to the original model within the `data` argument ...

Comment: @BenBolker Yes I agree, but I would like this to work also without the data argument (I do have that in my non-stripped function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the help for `update` (`?update`) it tells you this:

> **Description**
>
> update will update and (by default) re-fit a model. It does this by extracting the call stored in the object, updating the call and (by default) evaluating that call. Sometimes it is useful to call update with only one argument, for example if the data frame has been corrected.
>
> “Extracting the call” in update() and similar functions uses getCall() which itself is a (S3) generic function with a default method that simply gets x$call.
>
> Because of this, update() will often work (via its default method) on new model classes, either automatically, or by providing a simple getCall() method for that class.
>
> **Usage**
>
> update(object, ...)
>
> getCall(x, ...)

It looks to me like the clash is occurring because information is being passed through to the `getCall` function where `x` is the name of a parameter and this then experiences a name clash with your `x` and the language is choosing the local `x` over your `x`.

Comment: That was my thinking also, but I'm having hard time of figuring out why does adding `terms` component help this, as I don't see that it is used by `update.default` (or `update.formula`).

Comment: `terms.formula` does however.